# How would you transform a table with a variable number of locations for an ID so that locations become columns?

Tags: pivot, transform, transpose, powerquery, unpivot

I have a table with columns ID and Location. An ID can have multiple (let's say 5) locations. How do I transform the Source Table into the Target Table?

**Source Table**
**ID, Location**
Bldg A,Hallway
Bldg B,Back Hallway
Bldg B,Front Hallway
Bldg C,1st Floor
Bldg C,2nd Floor
Bldg C,3rd Floor

**Target Table**
**ID, Location1, Location2, Location3**
Bldg A,Hallway,,
Bldg B,Back Hallway,Front Hallway,
Bldg C,1st Floor,2nd Floor,3rd Floor

I have tried to transpose and pivot/unpivot but I cannot get the results I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Table1 has two columns ID and Location

Select the table and load into powerquery
Data...From Table Range ... [x] table has headers

Select/Click the ID column
right-click  Group By... [basic]  ... Group By:ID ...  New column Name:Data ... Operation:All Rows ... Column:blank

That will aggregate all the data for each ID into a table in its own column

Add Column..Custom Column....
New column name: Custom ... formula: =Table.Column([Data],"Location")

That will create a list for each ID that just has the locations in it

Click -><- arrows at top of Custom column, extract values, with comma

That will combine all the unique values for Location with a , to separate them

Final code (which you could also paste using Advanced...)

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID"}, {{"Data", each _, type table}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.Column([Data],"Location")),
#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text})
in #"Extracted Values"
```

Above has the benefit of being easier to follow, and able to be done using the interface.  If you want to get fancy you can use below ... a single step to aggregate the ID and combine the locations.  Paste using Advanced Editor

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID"}, {{"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Location], Text.From), ","), type text}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```